# Is 'reaction' the accepted term to encapsulate user response to social media posts

Tags: terminology, social-media

Since it was introduced by facebook I guess it will probably become mainstream and be accepted before long, but I am wondering if there was a term previously used for these types of elements on social media websites that indicate a user's emotional reaction or response to posts.

Also, is the term possibly ambiguous or confusing in other UX context?

Comment: What might have been in use, just can't remember the days before Facebook: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/309518/is-there-a-term-for-likes-and-dislikes-on-a-social-network

Comment: The first time I saw a Facebook notification that 8 users had reacted to my post, I was very confused.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Buzzfeed have been calling them **reactions** for ages. I hope Facebook's version ends up looking more like Buzzfeed's version.
[image]

You can see them in use on this article. [24 Medieval Reactions That Are Literally Your Life](http://www.buzzfeed.com/jobarrow/the-medieval-times-were-messed-up#.ki2xZvbozL)